# Javascript Asynchronous with setTimeout(..., 0)

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, event-loop

I wanted to have a better understanding of how the event loop and asynchronous code works in Javascript. There is a ton of resources online but I could not find an answer to my question

Everyday I mostly use callbacks, promises, async/awaits, but at the end I am simply relying on already asynchronous methods.

Therefore I wanted to know how it works, creating an async function from scratch, and deal with blocking code (or should I say slow code, that is not an HttpRequest or anything that is already provided to us).

For example taking while loop with a very high condition to stop it, should take a second to finish. And this is what I decided to implement for my tests.

After my research, I could read that one way of making my code asynchronous, would be to use `setTimeout` with a 0ms delay (placing a message in the event queue, that will be executed after the next tick)

```
function longOperation(cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var i = 0;
        while (i != 1000000000) { i++; }
        cb();
    }, 0);
}

longOperation(() => {
    console.log('callback finished');
})

console.log('start');
```

**My question is:**

When my code is finally going to be executed, why isn't it blocking anymore ? What is the difference between executing it normally, and placing a message that the event loop will pick to push it to the call stack ?

The following video shows how the event loop handles a `setTimeout` with 0 delay.

[JavaScript Event loop with setTimeout 0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IoBc3Vy3s3I)

However, the code executed is a simple console log. In my example, this is a "long" operation...

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. That `while` loop would block any other code from running.

Comment: It seemed to me that it was successfully asynchronous since I can place code after my "start" that will execute, and "callback finished" will print once the while loop is over

Comment: Yes, this is asynchronous. What is the problem?

Comment: There is no problem. It's working. I just don't understand how calling setTimeout will make my while loop not blocking anything anymore

Comment: @Scaraux it totally is blocking. Make it an infinite loop and check your CPU temperature.

Comment: the loop is still blocking - try interacting with the page while the loop is running

Comment: `setTimeout()` is asynchronous (non-blocking) function by js spec. I think that explains the behaviour of your code.

Comment: @JakeNoh `setTimeout` is not a part of ES standard.

Comment: @Scaraux actually your `while()` loop does block. your `cb()` is only fired when while loop is finished. So `setTimeout()` is asynchronous but while loop inside of a callback function (of `setTimeout()`) is synchronous.

Comment: @zerkms oh, I never knew that! thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @JakeNoh tbh I was surprised it's defined in the HTML standard, while I always thought it's a part of DOM. So TIL too. PS: kia ora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The outer code executes to completion.
2. The setTimeout 0 timer expires immediately, so its callback runs right away and executes to completion (the long-running `while` loop and its callback).

During both of these code execution phases, no other JavaScript user code will run.

Comment: So this is not really asynchronous, is it ?

Comment: @Scaraux Right, what you're doing is just deferred execution.

Comment: Alright. How can you transform my while loop logic or anything that takes “time”, to an asynchronous logic where it will be executed and notify when its done?

Comment: You could break up the loop into small chunks and use `setTimer` to execute a chunk at a time, but you can't create your own asynchronous JavaScript unless it's calling existing async functions provided by the JS runtime. Perhaps you're looking for [Web Worker threads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)? Maybe post a new question regarding the specifics of what you're actually trying to do.